# Eclipse - `open call hierarchy` stop searching in lambda chain

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, call-hierarchy

Here is my sample java code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methodDepth0(
            ()->
                methodDepth1(
                    ()->
                        methodDepth2()
                )
        );
    }

    static Object methodDepth2() {
        return null;
    }

    interface MyIF {
        void call();
    }

    static void methodDepth0(MyIF myIf){
        myIf.call();
    }

    interface MyIF2 {
        void call();
    }

    static void methodDepth1(MyIF2 myIf2){
        myIf2.call();
    }
}
```

When I open call hierarchy of method `methodDepth2()` from Eclipse(4.4), 
`open call hierarchy` stop searching next caller:
[image: open call hierarchy stop searching next caller method]

What I expect is like opening call hierarchy of method `methodDepth1()` which show until the `main` method.
[image: opening call hierarchy of method <code>methodDepth1()</code> which show until the <code>main</code> method]

Comment: A quick patch: https://goo.gl/2R0xH4

Comment: A good reason move to IntelliJ

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell the lack of call hierarchy depth is due to (re)evaluation of code at runtime.  It is explained in [*15.27.4* Run-Time Evaluation of Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4) in the Java Language Specification.

> At run time, evaluation of a lambda expression is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object. Evaluation of a lambda expression is distinct from execution of the lambda body.

Answer (score 0):

As the second picture clearly shows, Eclipse *is* able to trace the call hierarchy through the method call `myIf.call()` inside `methodDepth0`. This is correct, because the (outer) lambda implements method `MyIF.call()`.

The fact that the same pattern does not work in the next nesting level looks like a bug. Please consider [filing a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=UI) for JDT/UI. TIA.

Just note, that for lambdas implementing library types like `Consumer<T>`, the number of callers into `accept(T)` in a workspace may easily become unmanageable, similar to any call hierarchy through, e.g, `Runnable.run()` - but that doesn't question the general usefulness of call hierarchies through lambdas.

Comment: Thank you, I had filled this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468561

Comment: How Intellij is showing expected stacktrace? Are there any chances it can be fixed in the near future?